# How to route between two bridge interfaces?

Tags: iptables, bridge, lxc, iproute, lxd

So I have a total of two bridges.
One has the 10.0.0.1/24 subnet (br0), and the other has the 10.1.0.1/8 subnet (br1).

I want to setup an NGINX reverse proxy that would run on a container connected to br1, which will be proxying a server connected to br0.

However, when I simply attempt to ping from a LXC container on br0 to br1, the commands fail with messages like 'No route to host'.

How can I properly configure iproute and iptables so that packets between the two bridges are routed between them?

Comment: Perhaps the concept you are looking for is "router"?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around and experimentation with the 'ip route' command, a simple

'route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.1'

on the LXC container connected to br1 solved the problem!